# appcelerator save/retrieve images in specific album

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, location, appcelerator

I'm making a timetable for school. And i want to add an option to make notes from the lessons i have with my ipad, for example i have math now and i want to make notes from it and i want to save it in the album math ( if the album math doesn't exist i want to make the album math). I want to do this for every lesson, because i want to add an option to retrieve all the notes from a specific folder for example maths.Is it possible to do this? Many thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible. I don't know how much help you're looking for as regards to application design, but you'd probably be looking at saving data to an SQLite database using the [Titanium.Database API](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Database-module). You'd need a table to save notes to, and if you added a column which stored the lesson type you could then pull out all notes for a specific lesson. You'd probably also save the date so you could pull out lesson notes for a particular day too. In the app you'd just pull the data out and display it in a table. If you need any more specific info just comment.

Comment: before i save it in database i want to save it first in a tempfile, because i made a go back button in my painting app, every time an user touch the screen i take a screenshot from the view  and save it in a temp folder. When a user press save I make a new folder with the last saving and then i want to put it in database. But the problem is i Can't get all the files from a specific folder on ipad, it does work on simulator. i explained it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457549/appcelerator-retrieve-all-files-from-directory , i hope you understand what i mean. Many thanks