# appcelerator retrieve all files from directory

Tags: iphone, ipad, filesystems, titanium, appcelerator

im working on an Ipad paint application and i want to retrieve all files from a specific directory, and delete the last saved image. In the appcelerator simulator it all works perfect, but when i run my application on my ipad it stops at var fid = dfo.getDirectoryListing();
I don't know what i'm doing wrong because i know he saves the png files in the test folder on ipad (tested it with alert).

```
    //going to the folder, this works he shows alert
   var dfo = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + '/test');
        alert(dfo);
        //trying to get all the files, this works on emulator he shows all files. on ipad empty alert
    var fid = dfo.getDirectoryListing();
        alert(fid);
        //application stops here
    fid = fid.splice(1, fid.length - 1);
        alert(fid);
    var lengte = fid.length - 1;

if (lengte != -1) {
    var lengte2 = lengte -1;
     painter.clear();
     painter.setBackgroundImage(parent + '/back.png');
    painter.setBackgroundImage(parent + '/test/' + fid[lengte2]);
    var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(parent + '/test/' + fid[lengte]);
    file.deleteFile();
}
else{
  alert('going back is at his end');
     painter.clear();
     painter.setBackgroundImage(parent + '/back.png');

}
```

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get any error messages in Titanium Developer?

Comment: No, i don't. everything works

Comment: i'm using this because you don't have an edit/save option for pdfs in appcelerator. Now i open the pdf from the lesson lecture, and when a user press add note, i do webview.toImage() and open the picture in a painter view so people can add notes, in the view you have a back button (code above) when people want te go back to earlier paint in temp file. When they press save i save the image in a folder from the lesson and add it to sql database and delete the temp file. I will add thumbnails in a scrollview next to the pdf webview, so people can click the thumbnail they will see the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be saving your files to Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory not the resources directory.

I think the emulator is allowing it, but the device is not for security reasons..